# LG G4 can't boot past LG logo after rooting

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, unbricking, twrp, lg-g4

I unlocked my LG G4 device using [this](http://developer.lge.com/resource/mobile/RetrieveBootloader.dev?categoryId=CTULRS0702) guide and installed `twrp-3.2.0.2-1-h815` recovery.

All worked just well, then I downloaded [SuperSU by Chainfire](https://download.chainfire.eu/696/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.46.zip), placed it into my device and installed the SuperSU zip file from the recovery mode.

Now the phone doesn't boot up fully but gets stuck at the LG logo.

I'm out of ideas and I looked for solution for hours and found nothing.

Comment: can you get into  recovery mode (TWRP)?

Comment: yes i can,what now

Comment: Right now have a backup of current ROM, using backup option in TWRP. And, WAIT FOR A GOOD ANSWER. Or you can install ROM, root again and without superuser(bcz, that may repeats the same), for a running system. And you can extract apps and data from TWRP backup, using Titanium backup.